# How to showConfirmationDialog window form Struts Action

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts2-jquery, struts-validation

> Hi Experts,
>
> I want to know if it is possible in Struts 1.x to display a
>   confirmation dialog from Struts Action. In more detail :
>
> I have Action Form,Action Class and importList.jsp file. When i click
>   a button(on the main Jsp file) .. the current importList.jsp is
>   displayed by setting the properties of Action Form. In this jsp file i
>   have ok and cancel button. When i click OK button, on the basis of
>   some condition i want to show the confirmation dialog saying yes or
>   no, if the user clicks yes it will move forward, and on cancel.. it
>   will move to main jsp file(not to importList.jsp file)
>
> Any ideas ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to get this done. Instead of "Yes/No" dialog you will get "Ok/Cancel" dialog box. You will have to replace `"importList url"` and `"main page url"` with your actual urls.

This may not be syntactically accurate but it's a start.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
            var answer = confirm("You will be forwarded. ");
            if(answer){
                //your logic
                document.location.href="importList url";
            }else{
                //your logic
                document.location.href="main page url";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</body>
```

Comment: Can i call a function in java using jquery and return the result and on the basis of result show confirmation dialog...

Comment: Actually, i am also using struts action, here on the press of ok button, user submits the action, but before the action gets submitted, i want to call java function and on confirmation dialog 'yes' button i want to call struts submit action...i.e. document.forms['formname'].submit();